# jaxb bindings : package for namespace (scd) not working

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I am trying to map a package name to a namespace

As per the doc : https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configure-Target-Packages-in-Binding-Files

```
    <jaxb:bindings xmlns:tns="http://www.myexample.com/my-service/request" scd="x-schema::tns">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings >
            <jaxb:package name="com.request" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

It seems to be ignored.

see full sample : https://github.com/deslauriersp/jaxb-bindings-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to map namespace to a package with maven-jaxb2-plugin!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in XJC itsetf

the bindings are not working when using -wsdl option (which is experimental and officially not supported)

My solution was to includes all XSD but not the WSDL itself